# Cannot publish .net application or to install Web Deploy 3.5

Tags: vbscript, installation, web-deployment

When I tried to publish my .net application on the server using using Web Deploy 3.0 I got this error:

```
Web deployment task failed. Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UserAgent'
```

Searching the web I found that someone fixed this problem upgrading Web Deploy to version 3,.5.

When I tried to upgrade Web Deploy to the version 3.5 I got this error:

http://sciepa.org/zalek/pictures/WebDeploy3.5Failed.png

```
MSI (s) (78:1C) [13:26:40:909]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
DEBUG: Error 2738:  Could not access VBScript runtime for custom action 
MSI (s) (78:54) [13:26:40:916]: Product: Microsoft Web Deploy 3.5 -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2738
```

Then I tried to get current Web Deploy using Visual Studio 2013, and got this error:

http://sciepa.org/zalek/pictures/WebDeploy3.5FailedWithVS.png

Here are logs of the installation through Visual Studio:

http://sciepa.org/zalek/pictures/Log_with_vs_professional.txt

```
To fix error code is 2738 someone suggested this command:
[http://www.jakeludington.com/windows_7/20091115_error_2738_could_not_access_vbscript_run_time_for_custom_action.html][4]
I registered vbscript using command:
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 vbscript.dll

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 vbscript.dll
```

I also added to the PATH folders where vbscript.dll is located: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\;c:\windows\system32\`

but it didn't help.

Any ideas what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching, repairing system using SFC.EXE /SCANNOW command I found that the problem was  McAfee antivirus program. My PC come with McAfee, but I uninstall it it - at least this is what I thought I did.
This page explains how to do it in details:
[detail explanation](http://upandready.typepad.com/up_and_ready/2011/07/error-2738-installation-could-not-access-vbscript-run-time-for-custom-action.html)

What I did was to run this program:

[McAfee uninstall](http://download.mcafee.com/products/licensed/cust_support_patches/MCPR.exe)

Zalek